# uint8_t to Text

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am trying to use a Protocentral_MAX30102 Pulse Ox sensor to get SpO2 and serial write it to an SD logger. However, my serial write is a mess and I need is in a text form not what it is in now. I would live to write a CSV for to my SD card logger.

This is the stock code.

```
#include "Protocentral_MAX30102.h"
#include <Wire.h>

MAX30100 sensor;  //attach sensor
uint8_t data_len=8;      
uint8_t DataPacketHeader[15];
volatile unsigned int IRR,REDD;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(57600);
  while(!Serial);
  sensor.begin(pw1600, i50, sr100 );
}

void loop() {
    sensor.readSensor();        //read sensor
    IRR=sensor.IR;              
    REDD=sensor.RED;             
    DataPacketHeader[0] = 0x0A;
    DataPacketHeader[1] = 0xFA;Uni
    DataPacketHeader[2] = (uint8_t) (data_len);
    DataPacketHeader[3] = (uint8_t) (data_len>>8);
    DataPacketHeader[4] = 0x02;


    DataPacketHeader[5] = REDD;
    DataPacketHeader[6] = REDD>>8;
    DataPacketHeader[7] = REDD>>16;
    DataPacketHeader[8] = REDD>>24; 


    DataPacketHeader[9] = IRR;
    DataPacketHeader[10] = IRR>>8;
    DataPacketHeader[11] = IRR>>16;
    DataPacketHeader[12] = IRR>>24; 

    DataPacketHeader[13] = 0x00;
    DataPacketHeader[14] = 0x0b;

    for(int i=0; i<15; i++) // transmit the data
    {

       Serial.write(DataPacketHeader[i]);
     }

  delay(10);
}
```

Comment: You first need to define how your string looks like, and than convert each value to a string (or text characters you place/append in a character array).

Comment: You currently create binary data. Why? You want text, so just `Serial.print()` the data directly.